# Creating dynamic AlphabetIndexer based on cursor loader results

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, listadapter, android-cursorloader

I want to implement a list view with an AlphabetIndexer. I am using a cursorloader, so in my cursor adapter class I have the following :

```
public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor c) {
    // Create our indexer
    if (c != null) {
        alphaIndexer = new AlphabetIndexer(c, c.getColumnIndex(MyTable.KEY_FIRSTNAME),
            " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
    }
    return super.swapCursor(c);
}
```

The problem is that the names retrieved by the cursor from the database can be in different languages, and therefore A-Z is not sufficient enough. Therefore I need to create this letters list on the fly, when the adapter's swapCursor method is called. I thought about iterating the Cursor results and build the letters list then, but I am not sure it is allowed, considering this cursor is used by the list view.

Any ideas?

Comment: select distinct substr(field, 1, 1) from table

Comment: I think this code has problems. I had the code like this, but when I rotated screen cursor was closed, so I ran on error when getting column index on closed cursor.